# Post on Facebook Wall from Backend when image came from db in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-wall

I want to post the image on the facebook wall. I am using the facebookconnect for posting the file and refers the following [THIS BLOG](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-Post-Photo-Image-to-FaceBook-Wall-using-Graph-API-in-ASPNet.aspx).

My question is if i have the file path and i am getting the image than is it possible to post that on the facebook?? because FacebookConnect uses the HttpPostedFile for the image so how can i use this??

Comment: There is a Facebook C# SDK that you may find easier to use than the blog link you just supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with the help of the following URL.

[http://blog.impact-works.com/](http://blog.impact-works.com/tag/facebook-c-library/)

This is the great tutorial for the facebook integration you just need to download the dll of the impactworks.fbgraph, this will guide you in all the way for integrating FB with asp.net

Have a nice day...